# Форма обратной связи не отправляет информацию на почту php

Tags: php, form

Функция работает, но на почту не приходят данные. Хотелось бы Вашего взгляда на сей код.

Низкий поклон!

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = 'me@example.com';
    $subject = 'Обратная связь';
    $message = '
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>'.$subject.'</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Имя: '.htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']).'</p>
            <p>E-mail: '.htmlspecialchars($_POST['femail']).'</p>
            <p>Сообщение: '.htmlspecialchars($_POST['fcomment']).'</p>
        </body>
    </html>';
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/thankyou.html");
}
```

Comment: и в спаме не приходят?

Comment: и в спаме тоже ничего нет(

Comment: И в логе ошибок на сервер тоже ничего? В логе почтового сервера?

Comment: проверте отправку почты - создайте отдельный php файл с $data = "test test test"; if(mail("ваш эмейл", "test", $data)){
 echo 'Send';
}else{
 echo 'not send';
}

Comment: Aleх, проверил не работает

Answer (score 1):

Проблема может заключаться в отключенном функционале самого mail, некоторые хостеры просто отключают функцию или отправку ей писем, чтобы пользователи просто так не слали письма с хостеровского почтовика.

Для отправки хороших писем лучше использовать сторонний почтовик - Яндекс, Google и т.д, или ваш корпоративный, если он есть. После регистрации на всех известных есть доступ через TLS по протоколам POP3,SNTP,IMAP, настройки (адрес сервера и порт) смотрите в выбранном почтовике, например для [Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/support/mail-new/mail-clients.html), для [Google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229). У себя на работе один раз настроил почту для домена (https://pdd.yandex.ru/) организации, завел ящик для рассылки, подключил к нему рассылку писем скриптом - и больше никаких проблем не было. Письма хорошие, подписанные, в спам не попадают.

Для непосредственной отправки писем можно использовать [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Маленький, удобный, умеет все что нужно в большинстве случаев + прикреплять файлы. Примеры кода по той же ссылке, examples.

Если проблема сохранится, воспользуйтесь флагом debug в классе `PHPMailer`, он выведет очень подробную информацию о том, что происходит. Помогает отловить 90% проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Основные проблемы могут быть две:

1. Хостинг (очевидно, бесплатный) блокирует отправку писем, чтобы Вы не слали всякий спам. Практически все бесплатные (и некоторые платные) хостинги так делают.
2. Многие хостинги, которые допускают использование php-функции mail(), блокируют отправку любого содержимого кроме текста. Вы же пытаетесь отправить html-код.

Если Вы уверены, что Ваш хостинг позволяет отправлять письма, попробуйте отправить просто строку текста, без разметки.